# Why does rails view "refresh"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just noticed this now and I can't tell if it's been here the whole time. When I tefresh my rails app there's a "hard reload" refresh time where it makes the whole screen white. I'm 99% certain this isn't typical in chrome. Like on SO I don't think they're using Ajax but the browser still knows to keep the elements that are unchanged still on a page and not draw fresh from a white screen

Is this because I'm in :development or something?

I'm only making an external call to google fonts and google CDN for jquery

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework like backbone or ember? In your logs, how long does the request take?

Comment: I'm using no framework, but I am using html5boilerplate.

Comment: It says 200 OK in 436ms (Views: 325.3ms | Activerecord: 25.0ms)

Comment: It even does this on my "inner" pages.. bogus ones like contact where theres hardly any mysql going on. Contact page: Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 31.6ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried refreshing a few tabs I have open in Chrome, and saw a blank white screen on all of them for a moment before the page reload finished. Examples of where I saw it include https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ and even http://stackoverflow.com (counter to what you're reporting), so I'd it's just normal on Chrome and you didn't notice before.

However, I will say that being in development mode usually makes that white screen last longer.

Comment: You're right actually... i could have sworn it didnt do this. i just double checked now that im not on my phone anymore. In that case then, how does stack overflow do it?

Comment: @Tallboy SO isn't a Rails app in dev mode. There are a ton of ways things can be cached.

Comment: @Tallboy do what? Have a shorter period with a blank screen? That's probably caching and other optimizations for loading times. And also (obviously) they aren't in development mode. Dev mode reloads a lot of stuff that gets cached for production so you don't have to restart the app all the time, but load times slow down a lot.